# Filling keys to chunked array

Tags: php, arrays, key, fill

I'm trying to fill keys in my chunked array. Array looks like this:

```
{
  "0": [
    "yes",
    "yes",
    "no",
    "no",
    "no",
    "no",
    "no"
  ],
  "1": [
    "no",
    "no",
    "yes",
    "no",
    "no",
    "no",
    "no"
  ],
  "2": [
    "no",
    "no",
    "yes",
    "no",
    "no",
    "no",
    "no"
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is to fill each of array with key from 1 to 7.

My code looks like this:

```
function fillKeys($keys, $value) {
    $return = array();
    foreach ( $keys as $key => $val ) {
        $return[is_array($val) ? $key : $val] = is_array($val) ? fillKeys($val, $value) : $value;
    }
    return $return;
}

    $test = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

    $chunked = array_chunk($zones, 7);

    $zone = array();
    foreach($chunked as $days) {
        foreach($days as $value) {
            $zone[] = fillKeys($test, $value);
        }

    }

    return $zone;
```

I tried to use array_fill_keys to but I'm always getting the same output:

```
[
  {
    "1": "yes",
    "2": "yes",
    "3": "yes",
    "4": "yes",
    "5": "yes",
    "6": "yes",
    "7": "yes"
  },
  {
    "1": "yes",
    "2": "yes",
    "3": "yes",
    "4": "yes",
    "5": "yes",
    "6": "yes",
    "7": "yes"
  },
  {
    "1": "no",
    "2": "no",
    "3": "no",
    "4": "no",
    "5": "no",
    "6": "no",
    "7": "no"
  }...
```

Any idea how I can get the output I want?

Comment: Is it really that important to increment the key of every inner element? Where does the data come from? Adding 1 there might be more logical.

Comment: Add a dummy new entry at the beginning of each subarray to shuffle the existing keys from 0-6 to 1-7; then unset the dummy key 0. `array_walk($myArrayData, function(&$values) { array_unshift($values, 'DUMMY'); unset($values[0]); });`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$arr= [
    "0" => [
        "yes",
        "yes",
        "no",
        "no",
        "no",
        "no",
        "no",
    ],
    "1" => [
        "no",
        "no",
        "yes",
        "no",
        "no",
        "no",
        "no",
    ],
    "2" => [
        "no",
        "no",
        "yes",
        "no",
        "no",
        "no",
        "no",
    ],
];
array_walk($arr, function (&$values) {
    array_unshift($values, 'Test');
    unset($values[0]);
});
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Here is working code [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c4ad5141291edb809929b79328da821f8955491)

Comment: Well it worked perfectly! Thanks to you and Mark Baker